# SSRS Export to CSV Error

Tags: excel, vba, csv, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report that has a column in it that when exported to Excel (XLSX) displays properly, but when exported to CSV, it gives an error that I can't seem to figure out how to fix.

The column value is the following expression (sorry for the formatting, SSRS makes it difficult to format this into an easily readable statement):

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SomeField1.Value) Or Fields!SomeField1.Value = "",
     "",
     (Replace("- " + Fields!SomeField1.Value, 
              ",", 
              vbCrLf + "-")))
 + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!SomeField2.Value) Or Fields!SomeField2.Value = "",
       "", 
       vbCrLf + "- " + Fields!SomeField2.Value)
```

The error displayed in the CSV file is:

[image: error]

The value in the CSV's formula bar shows `=- N/A`. The `-` seems to be what causes the error but I can't figure out why. This behavior is especially strange because there are other rows with values in the same column like `- Test comment` and `- Yet another testing comment` that display without any errors...

The `-` character is required because the business wants the column to display as a bulleted list. Is there any way to fix this without removing the `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the cell value with an apostrophe (the ' character) to tell Excel that the value you are entering into the cell is to be treated as text rather than a formula and should be displayed as-is.

[image: Using apostrophe to treat cell value text]

Comment: This only fixes the issue after the CSV has been generated by manual input of the `'` character. I need something that would fix it when SSRS renders the report to CSV. I've been trying to make this solution work with a custom function but it is quite the hassle and involves more nested `IIF` statements (which I would like to avoid...). Any suggestion on how to get it to render properly?

Comment: Ah I see.. it's hard to say without being there.  Are there special characters in the output that are screwing up the CSV? I'm happy to try and help if you are able to share the file.

Comment: Unfortunately this has client data and I don't have time to sanitize it. I think I'll probably use your solution and detect the render format to determine if I need to add the `'`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry don't have rep to comment but you can just add an extra IIF statement around your code block using Globals!RenderFormat = "CSV" to add formatting to the expression for that field. It shouldn't require an extra function (unless this is required for more than just the one field)

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was required for more than one field so I made it a function.